# How to prevent a page to reload after on submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm Writing a PHP Programming with the database, I submit the form data to be inserted into the database at the same page but when it is reload it gives the respected error. I want to block the reload of the page using javascript or jQuery but I did not get any idea for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
<form method=post>
<label for="name">Name </label>
<input type=text name=name size=30>
<br/>
<input type=submit value=Sent name=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I has close the form tag before the  here I could not do that.
the php script is

```
<?php
 $conn=pg_connect("host=hostname dbname=databasename user=username password=password") or die("Error, Could not connect".pg_last_error($conn));
$rs=pg_query($conn,"insert into tablename(name) values($_POST['name']");
if($rs)
{
 echo "Inserted";
 }
else
{
 echo "ERror is occured!";
}
?>
```

Consider name is a unique in database then the error is generate during resubmission of form...

[It is the second step when I submit the page after fillup the form..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeK6y.png)

[It occurs after the re-submission of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eflQ8.png)

Please Help me to resolve the problem..
                         Thanks....

Comment: that is the default behavior of submit. it will automatically reload the page if you dont want to reload the page use ajax request

Comment: a good way to start http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: is it possible using javaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript jquery to submit your form asynchronously. Instead of using input type submit, you can use button with attribute 'onclick' that will call your javascript function. Example of form post can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

In PHP file, you need to return useful result i.e status. From that status, you can decide the behaviour of your form after received the result either to proceed to other page or show errors.